# Navigation disappeared after adding tabBarController, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement tabBarController and I managed to do it, but now my navigation from screens that are inside tabBar disappeared. I tried inside every viewController in viewDidLoad setting isHidden to false, but didn't help. Code below is from my tabBarController.

```
class BottomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.viewControllers = [bookedTrips, bookedTripsDetails, needHelp]
    customizeTabBar()
}

func customizeTabBar() {
    tabBar.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.949, green: 0.949, blue: 0.949, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.tintColor = .init(red: 0.949, green: 0.392, blue: 0.153, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .init(red: 0.753, green: 0.753, blue: 0.753, alpha: 1)
}

lazy public var bookedTrips: BookedTripsListViewController = {
    let initialTabBar = BookedTripsListViewController(networkManager: NetworkManager())
    let tabBarItems = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: UIImage(named: "bag.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "bag.png"))
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tabBarItems.title, image: tabBarItems.image, selectedImage: tabBarItems.selectedImage)
    initialTabBar.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    return initialTabBar
}()

lazy public var bookedTripsDetails: TripDetailsViewController = {
    let initialTabBar = TripDetailsViewController()
    let tabBarItems = UITabBarItem(title: "Second", image: UIImage(named: "bag.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "bag.png"))
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tabBarItems.title, image: tabBarItems.image, selectedImage: tabBarItems.selectedImage)
    initialTabBar.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    return initialTabBar
}()

lazy public var needHelp: NeedHelpViewController = {
    let initialTabBar = NeedHelpViewController()
    let tabBarItems = UITabBarItem(title: "Third", image: UIImage(named: "bag.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "bag.png"))
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tabBarItems.title, image: tabBarItems.image, selectedImage: tabBarItems.selectedImage)
    initialTabBar.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    return initialTabBar
}()
}
```

Not sure is it relevant, but I set tabBar to be visible after login, so if login data is correct, show tabBar.

Comment: The controllers you had inside the tabor should be navigationController and then each tab has its own navigation stack. The tab bar will do nothing with the navigation.

Comment: should I set every controller that I want to show inside tabBar as rootController? @PtitXav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this, if anyone need help similar to this, solution is to set return type UINaviagtionController and set instance of viewController as rootController, example below.

```
   lazy public var bookedTrips: UINavigationController = {
    let initialTabBar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: BookedTripsListViewController(networkManager: NetworkManager()))
    let tabBarItems = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: UIImage(named: "bag.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "bag.png"))
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tabBarItems.title, image: tabBarItems.image, selectedImage: tabBarItems.selectedImage)
    initialTabBar.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    return initialTabBar
}()
```